# how to migrate Bigcommerce store in Magento2

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, migration, data-migration

I want to migrate Bigcommerce store to Magento2

I have check online with Litextension and carttocart extension but it's not giving 100% accurated data migrated...

If anyone have tried before, or any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: what data you need? customer, order, product

Comment: All details catalog price rule, cart price rule, coupons

Comment: you have i think 3-6 rules max, it is easy to restore them manually.

Comment: Okay if we need to migrate customer,order,product what you will suggest? @MagenX